# Copy site from LAMP to WAMP: relative paths don't work

Tags: php, wamp

I'm developping a website using MAMP and it is currently live on some Apache server, and working fine. 
However, a friend of mine copied the whole thing in the root directory of his WAMP server and on his machine, no relative path work (no includes, no images).

The website is developped with the MVC architecture. My friend copied the three folders (M,V and C) and the index.php into the root folder of WAMP (www).

In index.php you have for example the line "include (Modele/conexionBDD.php)"
however the server says "no such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\index.php"

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance,
Aurélie

Comment: The paths are wrong. We'd need more detail about the actual paths and the paths defined in the code before we can help.

Comment: Indeed, sorry about that.
The website is developped with the MVC architecture. My friend copied the three folders and the index.php in the root folder of WAMP (www).

in index.php you have the line "include (Modele/conexionBDD.php)"
however the server says "no such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\index.php"

Updated th post with those infos.

Answer (score 1):

Windows and UNIX (OSX) use different directory separators - hard to believe I know, but Windows uses `\` while UNIX uses `/`.

In PHP, the OS-specific directory separator is stored as the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. Try rewriting the path as:

```
include('Modele' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '/conexionBDD.php');
```

This path should now work on both OS's, but you will probably need to change all paths referenced.

Comment: It's hard to believe that there's no other way!
Also, i'm pretty sure many people develop websites on WAMP and they can successfully upload them to (linux) Apache servers all over the world without changing all their paths...

Comment: Maybe it's something else - try it with that line and see if the error goes/changes

Answer (score 0):

This include should work just fine

```
include (Modele/conexionBDD.php);
```

but should it not have the parameter in quotes?

```
include ('Modele/conexionBDD.php');
```

as PHP does the directory seperator changes for you. In fact it suggests you stick to the unix seperator when coding on Windows.

I realise you may have been using shorthand `My friend copied the three folders (M,V and C) and the index.php` but if your friend copied the subfolder `Modele` into `M` that may explain the issue.